# How to wait for WebEngine/Browser initialization in JavaFx application?

Tags: multithreading, browser, javafx, wait

I would like to create a custom FunctionPlotter component that is based on the JavaFx WebEngine. My plots will be shown in a browser. Before I execute my plot commands I have to wait until the browser has been initialized (it loads d3.js). Currently I do so by putting my plot expressions in a Runnable and pass that runnable to the FunctionPlotter. (The FunctionPlotter passes the runnable to the loading finished hook of the browser):

```
private FunctionPlotter plotter;
...

Runnable plotRunnable = ()->{
    plotter.plot("x^2");
}

plotter = new FunctionPlotter(plotRunnable);
```

However I would prefer following (blocking) work flow for the usage of my FunctionPlotter component:

```
Functionplotter plotter = new FunctionPlotter();
plotter.plot("x^2")
```

=> The FunctionPlotter should automatically wait until the wrapped browser has been initialized.

How should I do this in an JavaFx Application?

Inside the FunctionPlotter I could do something like

```
private Boolean isInitialized = false
...

ReadOnlyObjectProperty<State> state =  webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty();
state.addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
    boolean isSucceeded = (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED);
    if (isSucceeded) {
        isInitialized = true;
    }
});
webEngine.loadContent(initialBrowserContent);

waitUntilInitialLoadingIsFinished();
```

My actual question is how the method on the last line could be implemented. If I use following code, the application will wait for ever:

```
private void waitUntilBrowserIsInitialized() {
    while(!isInitialized){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I know that there is stuff like JavaFx Tasks, Platform.runLater(), Service, CountdownLatch ([JavaFX working with threads and GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708931/javafx-working-with-threads-and-gui)) but those did not help me (= I did not get it working). How can I wait in the main Thread until a Runnable is finished?

Here someone says that the JavaFx Application thread should never be blocked:

[Make JavaFX application thread wait for another Thread to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800410/make-javafx-application-thread-wait-for-another-thread-to-finish)

Any other suggestions?

**Edit**

Related question: [JavaFX/SWT WebView synchronous loadcontent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247872/javafx-swt-webview-synchronous-loadcontent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to wrap the plot functionality in an internal queue of plot instructions. The command

```
plotter.plot("x^2");
```

will not actually execute the plot but add a plot instruction to the queue. After the browser has been initialized, that queue will be worked through and the plot commands will be executed with a delay. While the browser is initializing I will show some kind of progress bar.

If you know a solution that does not need this delayed execution work around please let me know.